# Run-time error on usage of Integer.parseInt()

Tags: java, string, integer

I was trying to solve a problem to flip two input integers and add the resultant. The obvious way to do this would be by taking modulo and thus getting each digit and reconstructing it back, but I wanted to convert the integers to a string, thus rendering it easy to be flipped, and then reconverting it back to the int, adding it and returning answer.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;


    class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    /*
     * Read input from stdin and provide input before running
     * Use either of these methods for input

    //BufferedReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();
    int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
    */
    //Scanner
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = s.nextInt();
    String num1= " ";
    String modnum1= " ";
    String num2= " ";
    String modnum2= " ";
    int s1=0;
    int s2=0;
    while (N!=0)
    {
        int x=s.nextInt();
        int y=s.nextInt();
        //System.out.println(x+" "+y);
        num1=Integer.toString(x);
        num2=Integer.toString(y);
        for (int i=(num1.length()-1); i>=0; i--)
        {
            modnum1=modnum1 + num1.charAt(i);
        }
        //System.out.println(modnum1);
       // for (int j=(num1.length()-1); j>=0; j--)
        //{
          //  modnum2=modnum2 + num2.charAt(j);
        //}

        s1=Integer.parseInt(modnum1);
        System.out.println(s1);
        }

        N--;
    }

    //System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 543"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at chiller.main(chiller.java:40)
```

Line 40 is the line where I'm using `parseInt`. I used the `.trim()` hack too, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is the content of `modnum1`? I see a space as the first thing you put in it. Print it, but I'm guessing you might find that `s1=Integer.parseInt(modnum1.trim());` fixes it.

Comment: I don't think it is clever to init `modnum1` with a whitespace and then hope that a string like `" 1234"` would represent a valid number, which is obviously not the case.

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your question (like including error message). Question without clear problem description can't be useful for others with that problem (since they will not be able to find it) making it off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I added the error, can somebody help me now?

Comment: "I used the .trim() hack too, but it still doesn't work." then you used it incorrectly. Its purpose was to remove leading and trailing whitespaces in string, but based on error message you still have one leading space at start of `" 543"`. Since exception was thrown at `s1=Integer.parseInt(modnum1);` it suggests you didn't modify apply it on `modnum1`, or didn't store result of `trim` back in that variable. But instead of fixing content of `modnum1` it would be better to prevent its incorrect form. To do so initialize it with empty string `""` rather than with space `" "`.

Comment: BTW `N--` is out of loop because of that `}` before it so you will never reduce it to `0` to stop iterations.

Comment: Thanks Pshemo, initialization with an empty string solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is cause because Java couldn't parse `" 543"` as `Integer` due to leading whitespace. Only leading `+` or `-` signs are allowed as per [Integer.parseInt() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-).

You can fix it in your code by declaring `modnum1` as an empty String:

```
String modnum1 = "";
```

Comment: try it with new BigInteger(modnum1)

Comment: And please update the question with your new modifications